# change slider value automatically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

How can i change the value of jQuery ui slider on onload ?

actually what i need is "Auto Slider" ,it will automatically change ...

first i used `settimeout` to 3000 ,so after 3000 Milli seconds it will start work.

to change the value what i used is

```
$("selector").slider("value",0); // this is the first option
```

after finishing the first value change i need to change it to second,third etc ..

i tried `delay` but it still changing values at once ..

```
$("selector").slider("value",0).delay(2500).slider("value",45); //not working it changing to 45
```

how can i implement this ?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem with timeouts?

Answer (score 0):

Or else you could use setTimeout

```
var val = 10;
var one = function() {
    $("#slider").slider("value", val);
    setTimeout(function() {
        val = val + 10;
        $('#slider').slider("value", val);
        if( val < 100 ){
            one();
        }
    }, 100);
};

one();
​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/HfYHH/1/)